# Filling pdf with pypdf - values not shwoing corectly

Tags: python, pypdf

I'm trying to fill a pdf document, therefore I'm using the pypdf library with the following code:

```py
from pypdf import PdfReader, PdfWriter

data = {"ChildName": "Gülcan Özcan", "DateOfBirth": "1.1.11"}  # Demo Name
reader = PdfReader("tmp/Antrag.pdf")
writer = PdfWriter()

writer.append(reader)
writer.update_page_form_field_values(writer.pages[0], data)
writer.update_page_form_field_values(writer.pages[1], data)
with open("Antrag_output.pdf", "wb") as output_stream:
    writer.write(output_stream)
```

Now the output pdf is filled, but when the name contains symbols like ü,ö,ä,ß the pdf looks like
[image]

I was googling and looking for a solution, but nothing works. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Could your issue be caused by the program rendering the PDF? I adjusted your code to the actual field names (e.g. `countChild1Name`) and can see the name rendered properly, e.g.  `$ pdfgrep zcan Antrag_output.pdf
 Gülcan Özcan                         1.1.11`. Chrome also renders the PDF correctly, i.e. displaying the name as `Gülcan Özcan`.

Comment: Just FYI: I use `pypdf==3.11.1` on and [this code](https://gist.github.com/MartinThoma/aefa6add94a524dcb871d3c5b211d29c) works just fine. It's essentially the same as yours (just printing the pypdf version). I've viewed the Umlauts with Atril Document Viewer and Google Chrome PDF Viewer.

Comment: @oschlueter The problem only occurs in Acrobat (Reader).

Comment: @MartinThoma You are filing in the Umlaute into fname and lname. That's working fine. But when you change your code an fill it into other fields like countChild1Name, the error occurs again.

Comment: I made an intersting observation: When I change the order of the pages (so the former page 2 is now page 1 and former page 1 ist page 2 now) the problem doesn't occure anymore

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that pypdf decode the character in UTF-8 so it could be resolved doing so

```
  txt = 'Hélló wórld'
  data = unicode(txt, 'utf-8')
```

and pass `data` to your `writer.update_page_form_field_values`  function

Comment: There is no function called unicode()

Comment: could you share the pdf so i can help you better here is a link https://www.docdroid.net/ :)

Comment: https://docdro.id/HvUlMpM
For your information: I've changes some fieldnames

Comment: Yes, I have a copy of acrobat

Comment: I have created a name.fdf file and pastd in the code above, but now I'm getting the following error when opening the fdf: "This file is corrupt and cannot be repaired"

Comment: @KJ Now I can open the fdf and I the values are displayed correctly. But how can I usw the fdf file with python?